# Waiting for a thread to finish with .join incosistent

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider this code:

```
    public class print extends Thread {

public void run() {
    Out.print("Hello");
    Out.println("World");
}
}

public class test {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new print();
    Thread t2 = new print();
    Thread t3 = new print();
    Thread t4 = new print();
    Thread t5 = new print();

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    t5.start();

    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
        t5.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

}

The goal is to print out hello, than world in the next line.The output isn't right,and it is very inconsistent, meaning every few test it changes.I've never worked with threads,but I did some reaserch and it says that using this .join should wait for one thread to finish so that the next one starts. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: most likely your PC is too fast - in the time when threads 2 to 5 are created thread 1 could already be done. What you do is tell all the threads: "Go write hello and then world". and then you wait that the first is done - but all the others print at any time they feel like it

Comment: You could add current thread name to the outputs and see that everything is all over the place :-)

Comment: Okay,so how do I tell the others to wait as well?

Comment: *wait for one thread to finish so that the next one starts*  Why would you think that?  Your posted code calls `start()` five times in a row without ever calling `join()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and it says that using this .join should wait for one thread to finish so that the next one starts

That is not what `join` does.

`join` blocks the *current* thread until the target thread is finished. It does not do anything about any other threads.

In your case, the main thread will wait for `t1` to finish, then for `t2` and so on. But it does nothing to schedule how `t1` runs in relation to `t2`. In particular, it also does not delay starting `t2`. `t2` starts when you said `t2.start()`.

> Okay,so how do I tell the others to wait as well?

Ideally you use higher level constructs like work queues and executor services instead of messing with low-level threading primitives.

If you do want to continue doing that, look at `ReentrantLock` or `CountDownLatch`. Or have `t1` call `t2.join()`.

I would probably use a `CountDownLatch`. Set up the latch to require five tickets, then each of your threads can print the first line, then block at the latch, and only when the latch releases (which happens when all five have arrived), they will continue to print the second line.

Also note that if you want to run these tasks in a sequence one after the other, you do not need multiple threads at all. Just do `t1.run(); t2.run(); t3.run();` on the same thread.

Comment: Okay, so how do I schedule them? Do I need to synchronize them?